# Making production-ready + securing a server (Ubuntu 22.04, NodeJS, nginx)

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, security, node.js

I started working for a startup as a full stack developer. The product is a SaaS that has been developed by an external company, and they take care of the hosting as well. My boss wants the app on our own servers, and I will be in charge for this.

We will host the app (a NodeJS project, only an API, the frontend is a mobile app) on a DigitalOcean droplet (Ubuntu 22.04). My question is: how can I make sure most of the data (like .env-files) and the server itself are safe? How can I protect this setup against different kind of attacks, like brute-force attacks, DDOS attacks, … .

The steps I already did:

1. Created a non-root user with sudo privileges and the ability to ssh into the server
2. Disabled root login
3. Set ufw to allow only 22, 80 and 443
4. Installed NodeJS v18
5. The app is using pm2 as a process manager
6. Installed nginx to use as a reverse proxy
7. Installed fail2ban
8. Added the domain name thats pointing to the server to Cloudflare
9. Added a WAF rule to Cloudflare blocking traffic thatis suspicious, from countries like N Korea, Iran, … or possibly known bots or a threat score >25
10. Added SSL (lets encrypt) to the server

I only have a few months of experience with server management. These steps I got from collecting information on the internet.

Can someone tell me which extra steps are extremely important to make the server (and the app) production ready?

All tips would be really helpful!

Extra information: it’s an app for use only in Belgium, so it’s ok traffic from like N Korea is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

This is bit difficult because to secure a server that's always depending on the security requirements of an organization. And making it production ready requires quite some experience. Having cloudflare is very good as a first layer of defense

1. Maybe run some hardening ansible playbooks to secure the server.
   https://github.com/konstruktoid/ansible-role-hardening (be careful this can break things)
2. Forward the logs to a syslog server or graylog,and make sure an team keeps an eye on it or any other log management tool
3. Do some load testing to see if the server is sized properly and can handle the traffic
4. Optional: Implement/configure backup

But personally I think it's not best practice to run workloads like this on a single server. I always say one is zero.

Comment: With your last remark: do you mean I should use at least 2 servers in production? Behind a load balancer?